# HTML5 nesting of <video> and <figure> tags inside <ul>

Tags: html

I am using webmatrix for developing  a website but there is an error showing that Element 'figure' cannot be nested inside element 'ul'.
And same error is for `<video>` tag??
Is this not allowed?
And the browsers also not playing the video!!
What should I do??

Comment: Put them in list items first? `<li><figure></li>`

Answer (score 0):

I tried it out with the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<ul>
<figure><img src="" alt="I work!" /></figure>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

This seemed to work just fine, so maybe you made a spelling mistake? If that is not the case please post your code.